# Why is my program not properly checking to see if the list already contains a particular char?

Tags: java

I'm making a class which parses through all the chars in a file and finds the amount of occurrences of each letter.

At one step, as I'm going through the file adding the characters, I check if the list of characters already contains the particular character I'm at. If it doesn't, it adds it to the list with an occurrence value of 1, and if it does already contain it, it increments the value of occurrence by 1.

However, my below code is not properly figuring out whether or not the list already contains a specific character.

I'm using an ArrayList, and I know I have to override the equals method in my CharProfile class, which I did, in order to have the equals() method that contains() uses work properly.

overrode equals method in CharProfile:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this.character == ((Character)o)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class HuffmanCoder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the file to be read from: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();

        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        int charCount = 0;
        ArrayList<CharProfile> charOccurrences = new ArrayList<CharProfile>();

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            // Grabs the next word in the file and converts it into a char array
            String word = inputFile.next();
            char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();

            // Parses the word on a char-by-char basis
            for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
                if (wordArray[i] != ' ') {
                    charCount++;

                    // Constructs the list of chars and their respective number of occurrences
                    if (!charOccurrences.contains(wordArray[i])) {
                        charOccurrences.add(new CharProfile(wordArray[i]));
                    }
                    else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < charOccurrences.size(); j++) {
                            if (charOccurrences.get(j).getCharacter() == wordArray[i]) {
                                charOccurrences.get(j).incremementOccurrences();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Figure out each char's probability
        for (int i = 0; i < charOccurrences.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(charOccurrences.get(i).getCharacter());
        }
    }   
}
```

Full CharProfile class:

```
public class CharProfile {
    private char character;
    private int occurrences;
    private double probability;

    public CharProfile(char character) {
        this.character = character;
        occurrences = 1;
    }

    public void incremementOccurrences() {
        occurrences++;
    }

    public char getCharacter() {
        return character;
    }

    public void setCharacter(char character) {
        this.character = character;
    }

    public int getOccurrences() {
        return occurrences;
    }

    public void setOccurrences(int occurrences) {
        this.occurrences = occurrences;
    }

    public double getProbability() {
        return probability;
    }

    public void setProbability(double probability) {
        this.probability = probability;
    }

    public boolean equals(char character) {
        if (this.character == character) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this.character == ((Character)o)) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (this.character == ((Character)o).charValue()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Issue in a nutshell: Instead of return true when checking if the list already contains that char, it seems to always return false, resulting in every single char in the file being added to the list, when it should only be unique ones.

Comment: 1) ArrayList.contains does not have to invoke equals() on the list items; what would you expect if it invoked equals() on its argument? Or if it used its hashCode()? 2) Your equals() method violates the contract of Object.equals(). 3) 1 and 2 imply that your code is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: You are using the equals() method in a wrong way. It compares an object to a char. However, conceptually they are not the same.

Comment: @antiguru: It's comparing an object to a Character (which is an object). The issue here is that he's invoking contains(Character) instead of contains(CharProfile).

Comment: @ignis For the first issue, I would expect CharProfile.equals(char) to return a boolean value. For the second, isn't that the point of overriding it? I want it to. Does violating mean overriding?

Comment: @DougSmith. For the first reply, I don't see how it relates to point #1. For the second, you have to obey the javadoc of Object.equals, that states that equals is symmetric.

Comment: 1) You said what do I expect? What does that even mean? 2) What does symmetric even mean? Since when can't you override equals?

Comment: Okay, I'll keep it simple. Short answer: pass a CharProfile to  charOccurrences.contains, and don't write an equals() that compares your class with a class that does not know your class (Character does not know what a CharProfile is). Long answer: [see documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). If ArrayList invokes Character.equals, (and it's free to do so,) it will return false for every CharProfile, which is not what your code expects.

Comment: That worked, thank you, but isn't it as simple as the fact that I was passing a char to contains(), which wouldn't work, as equals asks for an object, not a primitive type?

Comment: It isn't related at all. Java autoboxes the char primitive into a Character object, so the signature of equals is satisfied. Instead, you wanted ArrayList to do something that's stated nowhere in the javadoc ([read here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)). It would have been the same if you had had String or JComponent in place of char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is comparing object reference only to be same and also instance being the `Character` not `CharProfile`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this.character == ((Character)o)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You need to change your equals method to accept the instance of `CharProfile` and compare the character value inside it as below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this.character == ((CharProfile)o).getCharacter()) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** your equal method is not being called because you are passing char to `contains` method.

Please change that to :

```
         // Constructs the list of chars and their respective number of occurrences
         CharProfile charProfile = new CharProfile(wordArray[i]);
         if (!charOccurrences.contains(charProfile)) {
              charOccurrences.add(charProfile);
         }
```

Comment: Huh? `this.character` returns a char, what would `this.character.charValue()` return? I implemented it otherwise, and it still doesn't work. Thank you, though.

Comment: @DougSmith: I didn't have any clue about `this.character` as you have not share the `CharProfile` but right side of comparison was `(Character)o`, which didn't look right. Can you please share your `CharProfile`? Also please share the exact problem. Is it like its overwriting the cars in your list and count is not right?

Comment: @DougSmith Please check the updated answer(EDIT). Also please refer the updated `equals` method. The argument being passed now is `CharProfile`.

Comment: @DougSmith After updating the `contains` call using `CharProfile` and updating your equals method, it seems to be working. Please validate and let me know, if there is any gap.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a classic mistake: confusing `==` with `equals()`.

In java (different from javascript):

- `==` tests if the two operands are *the same instance*
- `equals()` has a default behaviour the same as `==`, but when implemented usually tests if the two operands have the same *value*

If you change all your `==` to `.equals()` your problem should be fixed.

Your `equals()` method has too much code - it can be replaced with this, which does *exactly* the same thing:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this.character.equals(o);
}
```

But I would make it this, to handle all reasonable types:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Character) {
        return character.equals(o);
    }
    if (o instanceof CharProfile) {
        return character.equals(((CharProfile)o).character);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, when overriding `equals()` you should also override `hashCode()` to be consistent - ie return the hashCode of the value(s) being compared, like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return character.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: The value of character is char, as listed above. You can't use `equals()` on a primitive data type.